# Formulating Code and SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, datatable

I have a Table in DB named 'Retail'

```
CustomerID       Itemset
    1               1
    1               3
    1               7 
    2               6
    2               7
    3               4
    ...            ...
```

I want to write this table in Datatable 'Matrix' where the Rows are Itemset={1,2,3,4,5,6....,k} and Columns are CustomerID={1,2,3,4,...,x}
and the rows are 1 if the 'Itemset' belongs to the CustomerID.

The output I want is like..

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ............. x
 1 1  0  1  0  0  0  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 2 0  0  0  0  0  1  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 3 0  0  0  1  0  0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 4
 5
 6         /And so on!
 7
 8
 9
```

`
I tried to code it but the problem is in VS Parameters for SQL Query don't work with Loops.

This is my code-

```
 objConnection.Open()
Dim matrix As DataTable = New DataTable("Retail")
 intcount = 0
    For intcount = 1 To noofCustomerID_col
        matrix.Columns.Add(intcount, GetType(Integer))
    Next
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim workRow As DataRow
    Dim Boolin As Boolean    
For i = 1 To 9
        ObjCommand.CommandText = "Select count(*) from Retail Where CustomerID=@in and Itemset=@in"
        ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@in", i) {{I Get Error here as I can't Loop Parameters}}
        Boolin = ObjCommand.ExecuteScalar()

        workRow = matrix.NewRow()
        workRow(0) = i
        workRow(1) = Boolin
        matrix.Rows.Add(workRow)
    Next
```

Kindly Help. I know this code can completely be wrong and it's okay if you can suggest totally different way of doing it. I've been stuck for quite some time now! Thanks. 
If any clarification is needed I shall explain as many times needed in the comments.

Comment: Looks like you want to do a PIVOT and get a count of ItemSets per CustomerId.   Google "SQL PIVOT EXAMPLE".

Answer (score 0):

Like Tab Alleman suggested, SQL PIVOT can come handy here.
Dynamic SQL is also needed.

```
DECLARE @DynamicColumn  NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @DynamicQuery   NVARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @DynamicColumn = SELECT '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CustomerID) + '],'
                        FROM Retail AS Customer
                        ORDER BY CustomerID
                        FOR XML PATH('')

SELECT @DynamicColumn = SUBSTRING(@DynamicColumn, 0, DATALENGTH(@DynamicColumn) / 2)--REMOVE EXTRA ","


SELECT @DynamicQuery = 'SELECT *
                        FROM (  SELECT  CustomerID,
                                        ItemSet
                                FROM Retail) AS D
                        PIVOT
                        (
                            COUNT([CustomerID])
                            FOR Itemset IN (' +  @DynamicQuery  + ')
                        ) AS P'

EXECUTE(@DynamicQuery)
```